# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.Font

Tags: java, spring-boot

Getting this error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/Font] with root cause

**in**

```
WordDoc.setColWidth(colWidth, colWidthForSecond);
String fileName = WordDoc.generateWordDoc(title, "filename", "", null,"", 
tabledata,tabledata[0].length, "", null, "", null, 0, "", "");
```

Comment: which version of itext you are using?

Comment: I am using iText 1.3.1

Comment: Try iText 2.1.7

Comment: This exception occured now.   
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lowagie.text.rtf.style.RtfFont

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am late but for anyone looking for solution. Just add either Itext dependency or Openpdf runtime jar dependency in your application build.gradle or pom.xml.

```
runtime 'com.github.librepdf:openpdf:1.2.5'

or 

runtime 'com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try set this dependency in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```